# Storing a message meant for serial communication as a member variable in c++ viable solution?

Tags: c++, oop, serial-port

I am creating some C++ libraries from some simple C functions that primarily have to do with USB serial communication.  I am writing it with visual studio 2010 with the intent to port to mac and linux.

I currently have a SerialCommunication class and a PumpComm subclass.  Currently, there is a C function for CreateMessage(uint8 msg[]), SendMessage(uint8 msg[]), ReadSerial(uint8 readmsg[]) etc.

My question is: are there any disadvantages from changing msg[] to a member variable rather than a function parameter?  (pseudo code):

```
int main() 
{
    SerialPort sp;
    sp.OpenSerial("COM19");
    sp.CreateMessage("Messagetosend1234");
    sp.SendMsg();
}

class SerialPort 
{
private:
    uint8 msg[];

public:
    int32 OpenSerial();
    int32 CreateMessage(uint8 msg[]);

}
```

The advantages I see include: 1) the msg is clearly owned by the serial port it will be sent to,  2) the scope of the msg is the scope of the serial port, 3) the implementation of the msg can be hidden (when I add getters/setters).. So basically advantages of OOP.  I'm fairly new to c++ and OOP so I may be missing something, especially when it comes to serial communication.  Thanks for your time.

Comment: For sending a message, no, that is rare.  Unless you use overlapped I/O but your code structure would look very different if you did.  Receiving a message is an entirely different ballgame, you almost always need a buffer for that since you'll get bits and pieces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are messages part of the COM channel? I'd say you send messages *over* the channel. You design is tightly coupling the "how" (channel) with "what" (message). Also, you implicitly add a lot of state dependencies to your code - for example you have to call CreateMessage before calling SendMsg.

To sum up, there are some things that might backfire at you later:

- If you need to access the channel from multiple threads
- If your message becomes more than a byte buffer
- If you refactor your code and mistakenly swap some calls

Therefore I'd keep message and channel two separate classes:

```
class Message {
private:
  uint8 *buffer;
  size_t length;

public:
  Message(uint8 *buf, size_t len) : buffer(buf), length(len) { }

  size_t getLength() const { return length; }
  const uint8 *getData() const { return buffer; }
};

class SerialPort 
{
public:
    int32 OpenSerial();
    int32 SendMsg(const Message& msg);

}
```

Comment: So I ended up using your solution but modified SerialPort::SendMsg to be SendMsg(uint8* buff, size_t len) because it will probably always use a buffer due to the WriteFile function that windows uses for serial ports.  Then I can always have a uint8* Message.to_buffer() function and call SendMsg(msg.to_buffer()), and change the implementation of Message as needed.

Comment: I think you are overcomplicating this. The Message class exists just because it should be passed as a parameter to various channels. If you ever need to move to other systems or extend information about your message (for example whether it should be split into more packets), you get in trouble.

Comment: Ah.  I was afraid that changing the implementation of message to e.g. a std::string would require me to change the SerialPort class, but now I see that I call getData() on the passed msg and get a uint8* no matter what the implementation is.  Thanks for the help.